# Flag rows into groups of one thousand using helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to group data into batches of 1000 with the aid of a helper column, so that I don't have to keep typing out specific ranges to select them.

I came up with a formula for a helper column, but it is an imperfect solution:

```
=IFS(ROW()<=1001,1,ROW()<=2001,2,ROW()<=3001,3,ROW()<=4001,4,ROW()<=5001,5)
```

Is there not a better way of writing something to do the same job but that is infinitely scalable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ..., as with `ROW()`, but need 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ..., so ten times 1, then ten times 2, then ten times 3 and so on, then divide by 10 and take integer result.

```
=INT((ROW()-1)/10)+1
```

In `A1` and filled down will get ten times 1, then ten times 2, then ten times 3 and so on.

Instead of `-1` you can provide the start row different

```
=INT((ROW()-2)/10)+1
```

will start the counting at row 2.

Now change the `10` to `1000` as you need thousand times 1, then thousand times 2, then thousand times 3 and so on.

```
=INT((ROW()-2)/1000)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, you could enter a formula like:

```
=INT((SEQUENCE(COUNTA($A:$A))-1)/1000)+1
```

and it will spill down.

The `COUNTA(...` is merely to limit how far down the helper column is populated. If you want to populate the entire column, replace `COUNTA` with `ROWS` and enter the formula in Row 1.

But there may be simpler methods of solving your actual problem.